# How to give class to AngularJS Popup

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, popup

This is my code. when i click it, it show me a popup with its automated generated CSS. I want to make some changes to the CSS by calling some ids and classes. how can i give id or classes to it so that i can make changes in CSS by calling classes or ids.

```
$scope.showPopup = function() {
$scope.data = {}

// An elaborate, custom popup
    var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({

  title: 'Social Media Services',

  scope: $scope,
  buttons: [
  { 
  type :'ion-social-facebook positive button-large',

      onTap: function(e) {
       //$cordovaSpinnerDialog.show("aaa", "aaaa");
         window.open('https://www.facebook.com/BinDawood.Co', '_system', 'location=yes');
      }
    },
    { type :'ion-social-twitter calm',
      onTap: function(e) {
      // $cordovaSpinnerDialog.show("aaa", "aaaa");
         window.open('https://twitter.com/BinDawoodco', '_system', 'location=yes');
      }
    },
    {  type :'ion-social-pinterest assertive',
      onTap: function(e) {
      // $cordovaSpinnerDialog.show("aaa", "aaaa");
          window.open('http://pinterest.com/bindawoodco', '_system', 'location=yes');
      }
    },

  ]
});
myPopup.then(function(res) {
  console.log('Tapped!', res);
});
```

};

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute `cssClass` in the object passed as parameter of $ionicPopup.show.

```
  cssClass: '', // String, The custom CSS class name
```